# Force single application to communicate over data plan -- NOT Wifi

Tags: mobile-data

This is the opposite of most questions out there.

My friend's work has blocked a chat application, but she still wants to be able to use the wifi there for the rest of her internet needs.

Is there any way she can have *just* the chat application use the cell network (getting around the block) and have the rest of her browsing routed over wifi?

Comment: I don't think you would be able to use both networks simultaneously without rooting and manually inserting routes. But there are many possible ways to bypass blockage, depending on the method used for blocking.